# Cannot set style on leaflet L.geoJSON layer

Tags: leaflet, geojson

I am having a bit of trouble setting the style on a `L.geoJSON` based layer,my code looks like this:

```
var addProperties = function addProperties(prop,map)
{
    //the API does not seem to support adding properties to an existing feature,
    //the idea here is simple:
    //(1) currentFeature.toGeoJson() needs to be called to obtain a json representation
    //(2) set the properties on the geojson
    //(3) create a new feature based on the geojson
    //(4) remove res and add the new feature as res

    var style = function style(feature){
        var markerStyle = {
            draggable: 'true', 
            icon: L.AwesomeMarkers.icon({
            icon: 'link', 
            prefix: 'glyphicon', 
            markerColor: 'red', 
            spin: true
           })
        };
        if(feature.geometry.type==='Point')
            return markerStyle;
    };

    var onEachFeature = function onEachFeature(feature,layer){
        console.log("Inside on each feature,checking to see if feature was passed to it ",feature);
        layer.on('click',function(e){
            //open display sidebar
            console.log("Checking to see if setupTabs exists ",setupTabs);
            setupTabs('#display-feature-tabs');
            console.log("Checking to see if featureInfo exists ",featureInfo);
            var featureInfoAPI =featureInfo('feature-properties');
            featureInfoAPI.swap(feature.properties);
             setTimeout(function() {
                    sidebar.show();
                }, 100);
        });
    };  

    console.log("Inside add properties");
    var geoJSON,feature;
    if(res != null)
    {
        geoJSON = res.toGeoJSON();
        geoJSON.properties = prop;
        console.log(geoJSON);
        feature = L.geoJson(geoJSON,{style:style,onEachFeature:onEachFeature});
        console.log("The new feature that has been created  ",feature);
        removeFeature(map);
        addFeature(feature);
        feature.addTo(map);

    }   
};
```

I have also tried the `style` method as well,I am looking to add styles to the active layer for points(styles will also be added for lines and polylines by type).

Comment: how does your geojson look like?

Answer (score 1):

To style point features, you should use `pointToLayer` option instead.